# Using only a compass and a straightedge, what construction can ALWAYS be done by using a compass only twice?

Tags: geometry

Using only a compass and a straightedge, what construction can ALWAYS be done by using a compass ONLY TWICE.

?

Comment: only twice means exactly twice or maximum twice?

Comment: I am assuming from the question it is to be exactly two times.

Comment: Then here's your answer below!

Comment: Note that real "straight-edge and compass" constructions do not really allow you to retain the distance in the compass as you lift it up to place it somewhere else. You're only ever allowed to put the point of the compass at an already marked point, put the pen in another, and make a circle. Fortunately for most of us, it's possible to"transfer" a distance from one point to another with this limitation, which means that in practice, we're allowed to retain the distance. Unfortuantely for you, it takes a couple of circles to do it. Thus an equilateral triangle is about all you can get.

Comment: I suspect that the intention was to allow the compass to be used twice, and the straightedge to be used as many times as desired.  Otherwise the mention of "[u]sing ... a straightedge" would be of no import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clearly make a equilateral triangle. Indeed just make a circonference. After that, draw a straight line through the origin with the straightedge. You will find a diameter which intersects the circonference in two points. Put the compass in one of those two points, with the drawing bit of the compass at the center of the circle. Hence draw half of a cinconference and it will intersect the circle in two points. Connecting these two points with the point opposite to where you pointed your compass, will give you the triangle.

[Triangle with compass](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=triangolo%20equilatero%20compasso&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirvJWN5ezQAhWmKsAKHeU-CFkQ_AUICCgB&biw=1242&bih=562#imgrc=E9YZBQYVG8kWDM%3A)

[image: Triangle Photo]

Another way, which is the typical way used by graphic students (or engineers) is the following: 
[image: Triangle - Easier]

Comment: Another plane geometry construction that needs but two applications of the compass is finding the midpoint between two points.